# Solving font issues on mobile when it works on tablet and desktop

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and would like to get some help and see where I'm making a mistake. The font is working on the desktop and tablet. It also works in horizontal view on mobile, but has issues when it's in vertical mode on the mobile and becomes blurry.

I have already tried changing the font from pixels to ems, but still not luck in fixing the problem.

Here are some pictures of what it looks like:

[image]
[image]

Also here is another example:

[image]
[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
.price-layout{
    width: 960px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.price-layout #product-image{
    border: 0 solid;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 37px;
    margin-right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 196px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.price-layout #product-details{
    float: left;
    width: 625px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.price-layout #product-details h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.price-layout #product-details h2{
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.price-layout #product-details h3{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 70%;
}
.price-layout #product-details h3 span{
    float:right;

    font-size: 20px;
    font-style:italic;
}

.price-layout #product-details h3 span a{
color: #33628c; 
}

.price-layout #product-details h3 span a:hover {
    float:right;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style:italic;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}


.price-layout #product-details  ul.product-status-tabs a{
    background-image: url("images/websites/odot.jpg");
    background-position: 0 -70px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #676767;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 30px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding-left: 36px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.price-layout #product-details  ul.product-status-tabs a:hover, .price-layout #product-details  ul.product-status-tabs a.active{
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #33628c;
}
.price-layout #product-details  ul.product-status-tabs p{
    color: #333333;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
.price-layout #product-details ul.product-status-tabs{
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.price-layout #product-details ul.product-status-tabs li{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}


.product-tab-pane {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
    border-top: 2px solid #4E6385;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.product-tab-pane:after, .product-tab-pane:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.product-tab-pane:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #33628c;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.product-tab-pane:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #33628c;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
.product-tab-pane p{
    color: #434343;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.product-tab-pane ul{
    margin: 0 0 0 18px;
    padding: 0;
}
.product-tab-pane li{
    color: #434343;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.product-status-tab-contents{
    font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.product-status-tab-contents #broken:after, .product-status-tab-contents #broken:before  {
    margin-left: -312px;
}
.product-status-tab-contents  #good:after, .product-status-tab-contents  #good:before {
    margin-left: -112px;
}
.product-status-tab-contents #flawless:after, .product-status-tab-contents #flawless:before {
    margin-left: 88px;
}
.rprice-row{
    border-top: 1px solid #33628c;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.rprice-row:hover{
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.rprice-row .price-info{
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
}
.rprice-row  a{
    color: #33628c;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.rprice-row .price-info h2{
    color: #33628c;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0 20 0 6px !important;
    padding: 0;
}
.rprice-row .price-info p{
    color: #A3A3A3;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 6px !important;
}
.rprice-row .price-site {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 240px;
}
.rprice-row .price-site ul{
    margin-top:-2px;
}
.rprice-row .price-site ul li{
    list-style:none;
    width:140px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #33628c;
    padding:4px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
}
.rprice-row .price-site ul li a{
    font-style:italic;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;

}
.rprice-row .price-site ul li:hover{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00AA51;
}
body a.get-paid{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #33628c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 26px;
    height: 65px;
    line-height: 65px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body a.get-paid:hover{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00AA51;
}
.related-price-list{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    margin: 20px -20px -20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
<div class="container" id="header">
<div id="logo">
<h1><img alt="" height="100" src="images/logo.jpg" usemap="#Map3" width="300" /><map id="Map3" name="Map3"><area alt="RecomHub" coords="33,12,238,85" href="/" shape="rect" /></map></h1>
</div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li class="current_page_item"></li>
    <li><a href="/sell/iPhone">iPhone</a></li>
    <li><a href="/sell/iPad">iPad</a></li>
    <li><a href="/how_it_works">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:-10px;margin-bottom:20px">
<div class="content">
<div class="content-inner">
<div id="splash">
<h2><strong>Sell your New, Used or Broken iPhone &amp; iPad</strong><br />
Select your Apple device to see what&#39;s it worth</h2>

<div style="margin-top:18px; width:100%;min-height:350px;">
<div><script>

                        </script>
<div class="home-rt iphone" style="opacity: 0.980668;">
<div class="recent-trade-img"><a href="/sell/iPhone"><img onmouseout="this.src='images/home_iPhone.jpg';" onmouseover="this.src='images/home_rollover_iPhone.jpg';" src="images/home_iPhone.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>

<div class="home-rt ipad" style="opacity: 0.980668;">
<div class="recent-trade-img"><a href="/sell/iPad"><img onmouseout="this.src='images/home_iPad.jpg';" onmouseover="this.src='images/home_Rollover_iPad.jpg';" src="images/home_iPad.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Well the phone works when it's in horizontal view, but not vertical so I don't think that is the issue. I've added the other code for the site

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { /*reset for mobile browsers */
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

For some reasons, if the font you are using doesn’t include a bold weight, then the browser will create a faux bold and offset that.

**Update**
The problem is specifically for some iPhone Safari browsers, so there are small chances of seeing it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate the issue on my android phone, assuming this is on your actual website. My guess would be a font rendering issue in webkit on iPhones. It happens when it tries to resize the font proportional to the screen size/layout. Try this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; 
    }
}
```

This should disable the font size adjustment on iPhones without impacting desktop webkit browsers.

You can find more information about the issue in this [Article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/beware_of_-webkit-text-size-adjustnone/).

Comment: Yes it seems to be only an issue with the iPhone, i tried what you suggested but no luck